# Drupal 7, Google Analytics, Downloads/username

Tags: drupal

I need to use the reporting system within Drupal (or a module) to report which file was downloaded by each registered user of my site. I can see the visited pages, but not the actual download event or file name.

Im also using Google Analytics, but it doesn't report which files have been downloaded by a specific username..or does it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your solution is setting *custom variables*. 
Go to the Google Analitycs config page, scroll down to custom variables & set these values:

**Name = user

Value = [current-user:name]

Scope = session OR visit**

You must also check **"Track downloads (clicks on file links) for the following extensions"** with the file extensions you want to track.

With these values you can define additional segments in your analytics. 
For more info check this page:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Hope that helps!